# How does JSLint's function-within-a-loop error apply when using jQuery's .each()?

Tags: jquery, jslint

I'm using a jQuery `.each()` call, which uses an anonymous function, from inside a `for` loop. JSLint comes up with the warning "Don't make functions within a loop".

Here's a code snippet from a larger function - in essence it is doing a check of whether each player of the game is still "alive" (has at least one piece on the board).

```
for( i=0 ; i<PLAYERLIMIT ; ++i ) {
    if( player[i].status !== 0 ) { //skip already dead players
        var stillAlive = false;
        $board.find("td").each( function() { //this func causes JSLint warning
            if( $(this).data("owner") === player[i].number ) {
                stillAlive = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if( !stillAlive ) {
            //... action to take for dead players
        }
    }
}
```

I can see how to remove this warning - just declare the function seperately and call it. But this is a very small one-shot function and essentially I consider this the body of a nested `for` loop, (I'm essentially reading the `.each()` call as something like `for $("td") in $board {}`)

Is this JSLint providing one of it's *style* warning, or is this more serious?
Basically, is it best for me to fix this?

I'd like to understand the reason for the warning, so any comments RE the why the warning exists would be useful (again I want to know if it's practical or style).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a style thing mainly, possibly some efficiency gained in IE, though newer JS engines will inline the function via their tracing engine anyway.  You can get rid of the JSLint "error" tough, like this:

```
function setupPlayer(player) {
  var stillAlive = false;
  $board.find("td").each( function() {
      if( $(this).data("owner") === player.number ) {
          stillAlive = true;
          return false;
      }
  });
  if( !stillAlive ) {
      //... action to take for dead players
  }
}

for(var i=0 ; i<PLAYERLIMIT ; ++i ) {
    if( player[i].status !== 0 ) { //skip already dead players
        setupPlayer(player[i]);
    }
}
```

*Should* you?  Personally I would ignore it in this case for the sake of maintainability, your current version is much easier to read/maintain, *to me*.  Your call here, which version suits *you* better?  Either way is likely to have little impact on performance.

---

*Bit of a tangent but related:*
What *would* have a bigger impact on performance is caching that `<td>` selector, DOM traversal is quite expensive.  I'd do this just before your `for` loop:

```
var cells = $board.find("td");
```

And use `cells` inside the loop, no need finding the same elements again :)

Comment: Good, style-wise I've happy with it as it stands, but given I've been unable to find anything that really *explains* the JSLint warnings it's difficult to know which I may safely disregard. Also, good catch on the `cells` suggestion - I'm doing that elsewhere already, but failed to utilise it here for some reason...  Thanks.

Comment: It _is_ actually more than just a style warning -- see @Sean McMillan's alternative answer below. The _only_ reason the original code example works correctly is that `$.each()` is guaranteed to run the function you pass it synchronously, before `$.each()` returns (and never run it after that). In any case where the function might be called _after the current iteration of its containing for loop_, then this form of code is dangerously bug-prone -- for the reasons described below.

Answer (score 3):

So, I believe JSLint is concerned about something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    $("#my-elem" + i.toString()).click(function() { alert(i)});
}
```

That will cause all elements with IDs my-elem0 - my-elem9 to alert "10" when clicked -- `i` is scoped to the containing function, not to the `for` loop. JSLint tries to protect you from this by telling you not to make functions in a loop. It's not smart enough to know that `each` will call your function now, and not later.